Azure policy not evaluating compliance correctly, non-compliance reason: Current value must not be equal to the target value
I have created a custom azure policy that checks if Logs and Metrics are enabled for Azure Firewall or not. But it is showing all the Azure firewall instances non-compliant, wherein diagnostics are enabled for all of them. I am not able to figure out what's going on.
Policy json:

{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].enabled",
              "equals": "true"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics[*].enabled",
              "equals": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Audit",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Audit"
    }
  }
}


===========================
btw, Reason for non-compliance
Current value must not be equal to the target value.
Field
type
Current value
"Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls"
Target value
"Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls"
I have tried taking references from other built in policies if I there is a value that I have put in wrong or incorrect, seems to be fine to me here.

ExistenceCondition can apply only to policy effect with AuditIfNotExists and DeployIfNotExists.

The ExistenceCondition can apply only to effect with AuditIfNotExists and DeployIfNotExists. Follow the Stack link by Deep.
Here is the updated policy to audit Azure firewall logs and metrics diagnostic settings.
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "AuditIfNotExists",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled",
              "equals": "true"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics.enabled",
              "equals": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}


Enabled log and metric for both firewalls.


Policy compliance result

